# How to create the title alert effect like Facebook?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, effect

How to create flashing title effect like facebook? Means, when you are chatting with someone and a new message is received, a title starts to switch between the original title and a message informing user of the arrival of new message giving a flashing effect.

Explanation by **AdrianoKF**:

> Notice the window title cycling between something like "New message from Foo Bar" and the regular one after receiving a new chat message.

Comment: Please describe the effect in detail. Not everyone uses Facebook. Also, I do use it, and I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: What title??? Are you talking about the `<title>` tag, a `<div>` in a page, something else? Programming is a specific science, so please be specific. *Kinda............* is not very specific.

Comment: OP's referring to the window title cycling between something like "New message from Foo Bar" and the regular one after receiving a new chat message, I suppose.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, chrome does not have title bar, but you can see the title in tabs. Please notice...

Comment: @AdrianoKF, exactly.....

Comment: @Darin, I think I caught you in a bad mood

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Code:

```
(function () {

var original = document.title;
var timeout;

window.flashTitle = function (newMsg, howManyTimes) {
    function step() {
        document.title = (document.title == original) ? newMsg : original;

        if (--howManyTimes > 0) {
            timeout = setTimeout(step, 1000);
        };
    };

    howManyTimes = parseInt(howManyTimes);

    if (isNaN(howManyTimes)) {
        howManyTimes = 5;
    };

    cancelFlashTitle(timeout);
    step();
};

window.cancelFlashTitle = function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    document.title = original;
};

}());
```

Usage:

```
flashTitle("New Message from Matt Lunn");
```

... or...

```
flashTitle("New Message from John Smith", 10); // toggles it 10 times.
```

Comment: For those (like me) who didn't realise, `cancelFlashTitle()` will stop the flashing!

Answer (score 12):

Set an interval that switches the title every few seconds. Untested code:

```
function flashTitle(pageTitle, newMessageTitle)
{
    if (document.title == pageTitle)
    {
        document.title = newMessageTitle;
    }
    else
    {
        document.title = pageTitle;
    }
}

setInterval("flashTitle('Facebook', 'New message from John Doe!')", 800);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval("var x='www.WHAK.com/Packer/',y='WHAK.com/Packer/',z=document;z.title=z.title==x?y:x",900);
```

Comment: It basically evals what's in the quotes every 900 milliseconds with a highly minified if statement (if its x, now make y or if it's y now make it x).You can minify your JS on http://javascript-packer.fav.cc/

Comment: `if(x==""){x=100}else{x=0};`
will minify to `x=""==x?100:0;`