# How to change document's tittle as facebook does when you got a new message in the facebook chat

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I use javascript:

```
document.title="something";
```

It does work internally.

I have also tried jQuery:

```
$(this).attr("title", "sometitle");
```

Which works inside $(document).ready(function(){});

But how can I change the tittle when any event happen? Like click on the button or something like that.

Comment: What's the question? Sounds like everything is working. You can change the title whenever you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create flashing page title effect like facebook?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381462/how-to-create-flashing-page-title-effect-like-facebook)

Comment: You should be using `$(document).attr("title", "sometitle");` instead of `$(this).attr("title", "sometitle");`.

Comment: I guess this is what you`re looking for:
[Make Browser Window Blink in Task Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122/make-browser-window-blink-in-task-bar)

Answer (score 1):

yes you can change it at anytime. example on click

```
$('#blah').click(function(){
    //do some stuff
    document.title = 'now changed'; 
});
```