# How do I toggle my website title when my users have unread messages from their friend?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Like in facebook, when we're chatting with someone and during that time while we're browsing another site in another tab, Facebook tab's title toggles, once it's 'Facebook', then it's 'Rehan messaged you'. How do I achieve this?

```
document.title = 'Rehan messaged you';
```

The above javascript code will change my site's title. But how do I make it toggle with the original Title which is the name of my website 'MySite.Com'?

Comment: Conceptually, you save the original title in a variable and then at "unread message" event you set the title to the new title and when on "user has read message" event you set it back to the original title.

Comment: something like this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/3381522/2359055](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3381522/2359055)

Comment: I want to keep it toggling from 'Mysite' to 'User messaged you' and again from 'User messaged you' to 'Mysite', until the user reads the message. After which the title will just be 'Mysite' without any toggling. @limelights

Comment: Ah, okay, I don't have facebook so their concept is unknown to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a relatively robust solution where you can add/remove any number of messages, each of which will be iterated over while displaying the base message in between each at your specified toggle interval.

```
/***Framework Code***/

//Configs
var BASE_MESSAGE = "MySite.Com";//Message to display every other time
var toggleInterval = 1000;//One second between each toggle

//Private Variables
var otherMessages = [];
var currentMessageIndex = 0;

/**
 * Updates the title, switching between the base text and iterating through 
 * the other messages
 */
var updateTitle = function(){
    //Toggle between messages
    if((currentMessage !== BASE_MESSAGE) || !otherMessages.length){
        //Display base message every other time
        document.title = BASE_MESSAGE;
    } else {
        //Display the next message in the list
        currentMessageIndex = currentMessageIndex++ %otherMessages.length;
        document.title = otherMessages[currentMessageIndex];
    }

    //Call again only if there are messages to show
    if(otherMessages.length){
        setTimeout(toggleInterval, updateTitle);
    }
};

/**
 * Adds a title message to display
 */
var addTitleMessage = function(message){
    otherMessages.push(message);

    //Avoid too many title updates
    if(otherMessages.length == 1){
        updateTitle();
    }
};

/**
 * Removes the specified title message from being displayed
 */
var removeTitleMessage = function(message){
    var removeIndex = otherMessages.indexOf(message);

    if(removeIndex != -1){
        otherMessages.splice(removeIndex, 1);
    }
};
```

.

```
/*** Your Code ***/
var newMessage = function(messageInfo){
    ..//Your normal new message code

    addTitleMessage(getMyDisplayMessage(messageInfo));
};

var readMessage = function(messageInfo){
    ..//Your normal read code

    removeTitleMessage(getMyDisplayMessage(messageInfo));
};

var getMyDisplayMessage = function(messageInfo){
    return messageInfo.name + " has messaged you.";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function:

```
var cont = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    if (cont % 2) {
        var myText = 'Text 1';
    } else {
        var myText = 'Another text';
    }
    document.title = myText;

    cont++;
},1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7bMjN/

I made use of jQuery but it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. In your case, code may be like that:

```
function toggleTitle() {
    if (document.title == 'MySite.Com') document.title = 'Rehan messsaged you';
    else document.title = 'MySite.Com'
}
var timer = setInterval(toggleTitle, 500);
```

this code will make your title change every 0.5 seconds. To stop that, use

> clearInterval(timer);

Comment: thanks, it worked just fine. And your code is neat and clean and easy to understand. :)