# Trying to make a web browser tab glow/flash in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get a web browser tab glow or flash when activity occurs on the page. I can handle telling when it needs to trigger, but I cannot figure out how to get a tab to glow. This may also be solved by a tab indicator.

Comment: You're trying to affect the UI of the program that renders the contents of your web page?

Comment: One of the ways to trigger this is by changing the title. There could be more, though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381462/how-to-create-flashing-page-title-effect-like-facebook

Comment: I meant something more like highlighting tabs in chrome.

Comment: Yes, changing the title while the tab is in the background will do that.