# Gain focus on tab if it's blured by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, blur

After I get some event form server, I want to gain focus on my tab if it is blured...
But, as I know, window.focus() method is blocked for some reasons...

I managed to achieve this effect, but the method I developed uses a kind of bad aproach, what it does is that, when the event comes, detects if my tab is blured, opens same tab from the very beggining by window.open and closes actual tab... for better understanding here is an example:

```
$(window).focus(function() {
    focused = true;
});
$(window).blur(function() {
    focused = false;

    setInterval(function() {
            if (!focused) 
            {
                window.open("example.html","_blank");
                window.close();
            }
    },5000);
});
```

if you have any better way to achieve this, I would be grateful...

With all the respect,

Ratty

Comment: So why don't you do what every major website does [gmail/facebook] and change the title. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381462/how-to-create-flashing-page-title-effect-like-facebook

Comment: I need it for sure...

Comment: You need *what* for sure?

Comment: I need to gain focus on a tab if it's blured after I resieve some event for sure

Comment: Your solution is not going to work when pop up blockers block the new window since no user event initiated it. You can not steal focus of the tab/window in modern browsers.

Comment: I know that, but that's all I have for now